# Was ist das Partizip Perfekt eines englischen Lehnwortes wie "booten"?

Tags: loanword, conjugation, past-participle, morphology

How do I form the perfect participle of an English loan word like *booten* (for a computer)?

---

Was ist das Partizip Perfekt eines englischen Lehnwortes wie *booten*?

> 1. Ich boote meinen Computer.
>      → Ich habe meinen Computer gebootet?
> 2. Ich adde einen Freund auf Facebook.
>      → Ich habe einen Freund auf Facebook geaddet?

Comment: Ich habe einen Freund facegebookt?

Comment: Book dich doch selber face!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ich denke nicht, dass man diese Sätze offiziell so schreiben sollte, aber in der gesprochenen Sprache sind beide Partizipien richtig gebildet.

Comment: +1. Allerdings sieht "gebootet" für mich weniger komisch aus als "geadded". Aber sicherlich ist in der Schriftsprache "hochgefahren" und "hinzugefügt" besser. ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Für viele englische Lehnwörter gibt es gute Übersetzungen, die man dann auch verwenden sollte:

> to download = herunterladen
>
> to boot = starten
>
> to add = hinzufügen

Allerdings findet man zunehmend auch solch Wörter, für die es keine Übersetzung geben kann, wie zum Beispiel:

> to google
>
> to twitter

In diesen Fällen wird meist versucht, allgemeine Regeln der Konjugation anzuwenden, was dann zunächst sehr holprig klingt:

> Ich habe mir die neuesten Updates ergoogelt.
>
> Das hat mir mein Kollege getwittert.

Welche Form sich durchsetzen wird, ist nur eine Frage der Zeit. Deutsch ist eine lebendige Sprache und offen für Lehnwörter. Immer dann, wenn ein solches Lehnwort sich durchgesetzt hat, wird es in den Duden aufgenommen und ist dann "offiziell". Es spricht aber nichts dagegen, diese Wörter bereits vorher einzusetzen.

Comment: +1 für den ersten Satz. Ich kriege jedes Mal Krämpfe wenn ich sehe, daß Windows etwas *gedownloaded* hat... :o)

Comment: Was sind die Formen, die von Microsoft oder Apple benutzen werden?

Comment: @deceze: Du meinst doch wohl hoffentlich "downgeloaded", oder? ;p

Comment: Das habe ich mal hochgevotet.

Comment: Nur eine Kleinigkeit... to boot im Sinne von Computer ist nicht "starten" sondern "hochfahren" oder vielleicht noch "anmachen". Ich kenne keinen der "starten" sagt.

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich mag das Wort *"hochfahren"* nicht (es fährt nichts und schon gar nicht nach oben), deshalb habe ich es absichtlich weggelassen. Für *re-boot* wird fast ausschließlich *"neu starten"* genommen. Natürlich ist *"hochfahren"* auch eine richtige Bezeichnung für *booten* ;)

Comment: Ich verwende gerne die deutschen Wörter für die drei ersten Beispiele. Ich sage "gegoogelt", nie "ergoogelt". Und twittern klingt doch schon wie ein deutsches Verb, also "getwittert".

Answer (score 6):

Wo immer möglich, ist es in vielen Fällen angenehmer für den Leser, wenn ein echtes deutsches Äquivalent genommen werden kann. Oft sind die erstaunlich naheliegend. 
Das klappt nur leider nicht in jedem Fall. Immer dann, wenn das Ergebnis eher grotesk wäre (z.B. Kellerzeiger statt Stackpointer), ist es sinnvoll das (bekannte) englische Wort als Fachwort zu akzeptieren und dann ist die Frage, wie es nun dekliniert/konjugiert werden kann, berechtigt.

Zur Konjugation von Verben hat das Institut für deutsche Sprache [einen Artikel veröffentlicht](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_kat=19&v_id=140), der diese Frage sehr überschaubar beantwortet.
Zur Deklination habe ich noch nichts gefunden, aber das mag daran liegen, daß sie unproblematischer abläuft.

Comment: *...und dann stellt sich auch die Frage wie es nun dekliniert/konjugiert werden kann* -> Also entw. wolltest du hier noch *nicht* anfügen, weil du auf deinen ersten Satz referenzierst oder ich frage dich jetzt: Wie lautet denn die Antwort auf die Frage, die hier aufkommt? (Oder meinetwegen kannst du auch sagen *und nur dann stellt sich die Frage*, womit du das aufkeimende Problem relativierst.)

Comment: Ich will damit sagen, daß in diesem Fall die ursprünglich gestellte Frage nach der Konjugation berechtigt ist, und nicht mit dem Vorschlag ein deutsches Wort zu nehmen abgebogen werden kann. Ich formuliere das mal um, da es offenbar mißverständlich ist, danke!

Comment: @TatjanaHeuser Danke :) So versteh' selbst ich das :)

Comment: Kellerzeiger ist natürlich eher missverständlich. Mir gefällt Keller als Übersetzung von Stack auch überhaupt nicht. Ich frage mich, wer darauf nur gekommen ist. Ich sage immer Stapel und statt "Stapelzeiger" würde ich "Zeiger auf den Stapel" sagen. Wenn es auch länger ist.

Answer (score 2):

Wieso immer so umständlich? Im Deutschen lässt sich das ganz ohne Probleme erledigen:

> Ich boote meinen Computer.
>
> Ich habe meinen Computer gebootet?

Ich habe meinen Computer neu gestartet.

> Ich adde einen Freund auf Facebook.
>
> Ich habe einen Freund auf Facebook geaddet?

Ich habe einen Freund auf Facebook hinzugefügt.